# Express static public folder not working on second page

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I set my applications up pretty much the same way every time and I have not seen this happen yet...

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

In main.handlebars

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

Folder structure

[image]

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.render("home", { layout: "main" });
});

router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login", { layout: "main" });
});
```

So the home page sees the styles.css file fine, but the second page does not.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I just changed the link to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
```

and it seems to be working.. I haven't had to do that before has anyone seen this?

Comment: just did...thanks